# Saving textarea through Ajax without bombarding server

Tags: javascript, ajax, client

I need to save textarea values to the server through Ajax.

- I don't want the user to have to click on a *Save* button. The text must be saved automatically.
- I don't want to bombard the server with new saving requests for every single key stroke.
- I must be sure the text is saved even if the user fills in the textarea and navigates quickly away from the current page.

If I do something like this, I'm sending a ton of spurious requests (code simplified):

```
jQuery("#mytextarea").on("input", function() {
   jQuery.ajax({...}); 
});
```

If I'm doing something like this, either the delay is too short and I'm still sending tons of requests for slow typists… or I risk losing the answer from users navigating quickly away:

```
var timeout = false;

jQuery("#mytextarea").on("input", function() {
   if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       jQuery.ajax({...}); 
   }, delay);
});
```

Is there a robust solution to send as few requests possible to the server while being sure that the input *will* be sent? Should I just stop worrying and bombard my server at every key stroke?

Comment: Instead of using a long polling (`setTimeout` way), you can try considering using a `keyup` event instead.

* On `keyup`, fire an event.
* Check the length of the content.
* If the length is greater than, say 10 characters, fire the AJAX call.

Wait, you are already doing it. `:D`

Comment: you could use a timer that fires once every second or two and do the save.  start/stop the timer with the focus events so you dont keep doing it when they tab away from the box

Comment: `Should I just stop worrying and bombard my server at every key stroke?`  No.. definitely not..  What you can do is Naggle the requests,.. I know lodash has a Naggle function you could use.  To really make this even better, if the textAreas can be large you would be best sending diffs.

Comment: Wow, learnt something new... `:)` Thanks @Keith... `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar  No probs,  lodash actually call it throttle,.. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#throttle

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar! I'd rather not add a new library to the application expressly for that issue though.

Comment: @FrançoisM. I didn't suggest you a new library. *thinking*

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry! got confused with Keith :)

Comment: Ha ha... Sure. No worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opting for waiting a certain delay before sending to server. To make sure no answer is lost, on page unload I check if there is currently a delay timer running. If there is, the answer is sent to server immediately. The request must be synchronous to be certain it resolves, albeit at the cost of a slight extra waiting time for the user.

Code (simplified):

```
var timeout = false;

//As long as the user does not stop inputting for (delay), no input is sent
jQuery("#mytextarea").on("input", function() {
    if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({...}); 
        timeout = false;
    }, delay);
});

//Send input to server on page unload, IF it was not already
jQuery(window).on("onload", function() {
    if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        jQuery.ajax({async: false, ...});
    }
});
```

Comment: The Beacon API sounds like it could be a better solution then blocking the browser with a synchronous request on page unload, but at the time of writing it is not yet supported in all browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API